# connection refused error when trying to close and open the browser

Tags: ruby, watir

I am new to watir and Ruby. I wrote a small code that tries to open a link, close the browser and then open the link again.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
br = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
br.goto "http://google.co.in/"
br.close
br.goto "http://google.co.in/"
```

when i try to execute this i get the following error

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `open'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `block in connect'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `connect'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.46.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:107:in `response_for'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.46.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:58:in `request'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.46.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.46.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:657:in `raw_execute'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.46.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:635:in `execute'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.46.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:133:in `get'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.46.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:33:in `to'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.8.0/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:76:in `goto'
from dummy.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

please tell me what to do. thanks.

Comment: it's like to dig one's own grave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like a human, Watir cannot go to a page in a closed browser. You have to create another browser instance, which will open another browser window. In that new browser window, you can then visit another web page.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
br = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
br.goto "http://google.co.in/"
br.close
br = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
br.goto "http://google.co.in/"
```

Comment: thanks, i understand what i missed.